# What exactly have I to do to create a child theme of a theme having more css files?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, wordpress-theming

I have to create a child theme to implement some changes to a WordPress theme and avoid losing these changes when the theme is updated. I have some doubt about how do it.

I am following this official tutorial: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

I have create the child theme directory (named `accesspress-parallax-child` because the directory of the original theme is `accesspress-parallax`) into the WordPress `wp-content/themes/` directory of my WordPress installation. I have put the `style.css` and the `functions.php` files in this new folder.

I have put this commented code in the `style.css` file (as explained into the documentation):

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Accesspress Parallax Child
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-fifteen-child/
 Description:  Accesspress Parallax Child Theme
 Author:       Andrea Nobili
 Author URI:   http://example.com
 Template:     accesspress-parallax
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  accesspress-parallax-child
*/
```

Now it says that I have to enqueue the parent and child theme stylesheets by putting this code into the `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
```

Now I have two doubts:

1. In the previous code snippet, do I have to refer to my parent theme in some way or not? How does it know what the parent theme is?
2. In the documentation it says:

> The following example function will only work if your Parent Theme
>   uses only one main style.css to hold all of the css. If your theme has
>   more than one .css file (eg. ie.css, style.css, main.css) then you
>   will have to make sure to maintain all of the Parent Theme
>   dependencies.

What exactly does this mean? In my original theme I have more than a single .css file. In fact, in the original theme I have a css directory that contains many css files.

What do I have to do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. It "knows" it's referring to the parent theme because [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) returns the URI to your parent theme. If you want the URI to your child theme, use [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri).
2. Since your parent theme includes multiple CSS files, you *may* need to enqueue each of them separately (if they aren't automatically enqueued). This varies by theme. If your styles are broken, make sure you re-enqueue anything you need by using `wp_enqueue_style()`, and `get_template_directory_uri()`.